# VLC cache and stream buffer freeze

Tags: caching, stream, vlc

I am using VLC to stream video footage from a video camera over an http network. I then have a second application that reads the video frames from the stream that VLC outputs. I notice that periodically, the video that is being displayed on the VLC interface is frozen but the counter on the tool bar at the bottom is still counting. The application that is reading from the VLC stream is still reading frames but the frames are delayed. Often by a few minutes. It's as if VLC has created a large buffer and is outputting frames at the beginning of the buffer instead of just outputting the most recent frame from the camera.

I think that what is happening is that there is a discrepancy between the frame rate of the camera and the VLC stream.

I have tried increasing the network cache time to 6000ms. Is there a setting I can change that forces VLC to output the most recent frame from the camera? I do not care if there are frames lost or dropped in between.

Comment: When I click on the right directional arrows on the bottom toolbar, the stream goes back to live. How do I ensure that the stream is always live without me having to click the double arrows?